# calling user management services on WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking at two WSO2 client samples that call the user management web service. The first is a simple client, the second is a web app.

The first client sets the system SSL properties and then instantiates a WSUserStoreManager object.

The second one, the web app, does not set SSL properties at all, and instead instantiates a RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.

Could someone please explain why these differences? What service to call when two similar are available (a regular and a 'remote' one)? Isn't it always necessary to set up the SSL properties when calling a https endpoint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling to HTTPS end point,  you need to set the SSL trust store properties to trust the server. But it is under control of the client, If client wants,  it can trust it, if not it can ignore. If you want to ignore, you want to override default TrustManager of java. 
However, normally java has a trust store file called  "cacerts" where it contains all trusted CA certificate. But WSO2IS server's certificate is a self signed one and java can not trust it. Therefore, if you want, you can import certificate in to the "cacerts file. I am not sure about why there are two different in client and web app. However, if you are calling HTTPS, trust must be created. Please check web app source more. Some time, it may have ignore the trust. As web app is run in a app server,  sometime java SSL trust properties may have been set to correct file.

Comment: Thank very much you for your answer. The app is this one https://github.com/soasecurity/soasecurity/tree/master/user-mgt/app/authentication and I did not find any reference to ssl in the code, so from your words I guess it assumes that the HTTPS endpoint certificate must be trusted on runtime (maybe WSO2AS).

Comment: Could you please explain briefly why there are normal and "remote" web services exposed? Is there any difference?

Comment: ps: your answer makes sense. the app works in wso2as but not in tomcat (cannot login).

Comment: Yes..  it is because, WSO2AS has the same keystores that is in the WSO2IS and the WSO2AS  has set those keystores as java SSL properties by default..  you may need add this SSL config in to the web app to get it work in tomcat (or other server) or else you need to import wso2carbon self sign certificate  in to java cacert which can be found at jre/lib/security